# Similar React components with different logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Desired outcome**

I want to have a reusable component, consisting of a title and a number.

The title is simple enough, as it is just a string, which I can send as a prop using

```
<ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent title="floorp"/>, docu...);
```

But the number will be calculated in a different way for each instance of the component.

**Question**

Is there a way to cleanly write such a component?

**My thoughts**

I'm thinking that inside the component, I would have a

```
calculate: function () {
    switch(title) {
        case 'floorp':
            //...
        case 'not_floorp':
            //...
    }
}
```

I will be needing at least six different cases, possibly (actually, probably) more later, so scalability is an important factor.

This is *the* way to do it, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would seperate the calculator logic from your component and just let the component worry about rendering views. Just make the component dependent on a calculator so it scales and is reusable.

Here is an example that has all your calculators in one file, but you certainly don't have to do this way, each calculator could be in its own file if you wanted (hence this approach gives you flexibility).

**calculators.js**

```
var CALCULATORS = {
    add: function(a,b){ return a + b; },
    subtract: function(a,b){ return a - b; },
    suprise: function(){ return Math.random(); }
};
```

Then you would just pass a calculator to your component like so:

```
<ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent title="floorp" calculator={CALCULATORS.add}/>, docu...);
```

Inside your component:

```
calculate: function () {
    //This will equate to '30' since we passed it the 'add' calculator above
    return this.props.calculator.call(this, 10, 20); 
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's way more modular and clean. Thanks!

Comment: :) Good luck with your app @Alec

Answer (score 0):

I think I disagree slightly with @jennas's approach. I think the component should only receive simple strings/integers for `title` and `number`, and the calculation logic should be done in a parent component or container somewhere above in the hierarchy.

Consider this, you're writing a different function for every type of calculation anyway, why bother passing it into the component? Why not just make the calculation outside of the component and pass in a plain value?

This achieves two goals:

1. You have one more dumb component, which is good because:

   - Dumb components are simpler and easier to test and share
   - Consumers of the component don't need to know how it works, they just need to know what it needs. For example, what values will the function need to make calculations on?
2. You congregate your app logic in more central places, where it can be more easily managed

However, to adequately answer the question I think it would be helpful to know:

- What is this component?
- What context is it in?

  - Is it a todo item with a "due in 2 days" notice?
  - Is it a draggable whose x and y coordinates are calculated on mouse move?
- Who else will be using it? Just you? Other people?

Comment: Yeah i must admit i did think of the parent component way too :) It's tricky since we don't see a complete context of the application in question as you mentioned. I like this approach too, If you do go this way; I would still seperate the calculators from the parent component (just import them instead). Its a good habit to get into to separating business logic from views. It means even they can be reused and unit tested.

Comment: Agreed, the calculations should definitely be imported from somewhere else.